# How to add a dropdown in Adminhtml Form Block, selecting data from a table referenced by foreign key?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, drop-downs

I am new to the StackExchange and this is my first question, so take it easy with me, please. :)

I am following to the letter this tutorial [here](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified), learning how to list, create, update and delete resources in the database, using Adminhtml grid's and forms.

I was able to do all the tasks proposed by the tutorial and got it up and running.

But now I want to add a dropdown field to the form, in order to grab items from another table, linked by foreign key.

The question below is most likely what I need, except the fact it is grabbing the select data from an array:

[How to add dropdown field for select custom option from admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156941/how-to-add-dropdown-field-for-select-custom-option-from-admin)

Does anyone have an example on how to do the above, but grabbing the select data from a database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remembering we are following this tutorial:
http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified

**The short answer is...**

Create the function below to serve as source to dropdown in the page `app\code\community\Foo\Bar\Block\Adminhtml\Baz\Edit\Form.php`

```
protected function _getChuz()
{
  $collection = Mage::getModel('foo_bar/chuz')->getCollection();
  $data_array=array();
  foreach($collection as $item) {
    $data_array[]=array('value'=>$item['id'],'label'=>$item['name']);
  }
  return($data_array);
}
```

... and add it to 'values' parameter in the 'select' field:

```
$fieldset->addField('chuz', 'select', array(
        'name'  => 'chuz',
        'label' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Chuz'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Chuz'),
        'values'   => $this->_getChuz(),
        'required'  => true
    ));
```

**And the long answer is...**

1) Add the new entity chuz to `app\code\community\Foo\Bar\etc\config.xml`

```
<foo_bar_mysql4>
    <class>Foo_Bar_Model_Mysql4</class>
    <entities>
       ...
       <chuz>
           <table>foo_bar_chuz</table>
       </chuz>
    </entities>
</foo_bar_mysql4>
```

2) In the file `app\code\community\Foo\Bar\sql\foo_bar_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php` do the following...

Add the new column `chuz` to the table `foo_bar_baz`

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
...
->addColumn('chuz', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_CLOB, 0, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
  ), 'Chuz');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

And make the script for creating new table `foo_bar_chuz`

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('foo_bar/chuz'))
->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
    ), 'ID')
->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_CLOB, 0, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Name');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

3) Create the Model files, as follows...

> app\code\community\Foo\Bar\Model\Chuz.php

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar_Model_Chuz extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('foo_bar/chuz');
  }
}
```

> app\code\community\Foo\Bar\Model\Mysql4\Chuz.php

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar_Model_Mysql4_Chuz extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('foo_bar/chuz', 'id');
  }
}
```

> app\code\community\Foo\Bar\Model\Mysql4\Chuz\Collection.php

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar_Model_Mysql4_Chuz_Collection extends 
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('foo_bar/chuz');
  }
}
```

4) Finally do the steps from the `Short Answer` part.

5) Do not forget to insert some rows to `foo_bar_chuz` manually, because we do not have create form for it!

**The result should be as follows:**

[image: Result image]

Comment: If I wanted to add a reason dropdown for quantity change on a product would it be the same?

Comment: Also, as of 1.6 _mysql4 is depreciated.